# How to get php to pass a variable to a second page

Tags: php

Firstly apologies. I am a complete novice. I wrote a small database over 10 years ago on whatever versions of php and mysql. I have managed to get the mysql piece working now but what I cant do is pass a variable from a selection page to another  page.

I want to choose a location and that variable I assign categorynum as the variable. I then want to hit submit and it open up a second page that will use the value of categorynum in another mysql search. However it doesnt pass over. if i hardcode and declate categorynum as a value it works so I am guessing its the passing from page 1 to page 2

PAGE 1

```
<form method="get" action="page2.php">
    
    <select name="categorynum">
      <?php
    foreach ($catByNum as $num=> $name){
        print "<option value=\"$name\">$name</option>\n";
    }
?>
    </select>
    
    <input type="text" name="categorynum" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Page 2

will pull in the word 'Submit' from the Value= piece (This is the wording that is on the button of the form on page 1 for submitting the choice)

Sorry if its really obvious

Comment: Change input type="text" to input type="submit". And delete name from this element, or rename it. Then your page will be redirected to page2.php?categorynum=selectedOptionValue where you can get the value with $_GET['categorynum']

Comment: Two of your form elements have the same `name="categorynum"`, give one  a different name. And maybe add a submit button

Comment: Thanks all. @digitalniweb - that was it exactly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In your current page, change the name of your submit button  `<input type="text" name="categorynumSubmit" value="Submit">` then inside the second page (**page2.php**), use `$_GET["categorynum"]` to get the categorynum value

EDITS: Note that `type="submit"` not `text`

Comment: That is no submit button though

Comment: maybe it's a  typo because this form has no submit button